# I want a custom JQL function to create subqueries for nfeed fields in Jira (via adaptavist scriptrunner). Any Ideas?

Tags: groovy, jira, jql

I want to create a custom JQL function that allows a subquery in nfeed fields. I am working with **adaptavist scriptrunner**.

In Jira it should work like this: `issueFunction in nFeedSubquery (nFeed_fieldname, subquery)`

for example:

```
project = xEpic and issuetype = Epic and issueFunction in nFeedSubquery("Related 
                         Product/s", issuetype = product and status = registered)
```

This JQL query should then search for Epics related to registered products.

Is this possible to do?

Any kind of ideas or help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd start with https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/4.3.9/jira/custom-jql-functions.html and experiment in a non production Jira instance

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do but I can't seem to figure out which method does what exactly. The documentation from atlessian is not really helping either. Maybe it's just me.
Have you worked with this already? Maybe you can explain a few things to me?

Comment: Have you tried using `issueFieldMatch` function?  It runs a query on any field by regular expression and has `subquery` and `fieldname` as arguments.